# Show div onclick not working (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Javascript newbie here. Anyone could let me know what is wrong with my code? The div-to-show does not show after click and I can't figure out why...

```js
let div = document.getElementById('div-to-show');

function openDiv() {
  if (div.style.display === 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
#div-to-show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="openDiv">Clique</p>
<div id="div-to-show">
  <p>I am visible</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Should be `onclick="openDiv()"`. But you should consider using JavaScript instead, with `let p = document.querySelector('p'); p.addEventListener("click", openDiv);`.

Comment: Thank you, why is it better to use EventListener?

Comment: It's about separation of concerns. HTML provides the structure of the document; the meaning and the relative importance of the text. JavaScript provides the behavior; what happens when the user interacts with the document. CSS provides the look of the document; how elements appear to the user.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems here.

First, you aren't invoking the function with `onclick="openDiv"` - you have to put `()` after a function name to invoke it, eg `onclick="openDiv()"`.

Secondly, although you have a CSS rule of `display: none`, that doesn't result in the CSS property *on the element itself* changing; it remains the empty string:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('div-to-show');

function openDiv() {
  console.log(div.style.display);
}
```

```css
#div-to-show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="openDiv()">Clique</p>
<div id="div-to-show">
  <p>I am visible</p>
</div>
```

Instead, to check whether the element is being displayed, you can check whether its `offsetParent` is null:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('div-to-show');

function openDiv() {
  div.style.display = div.offsetParent === null ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
#div-to-show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="openDiv()">Clique</p>
<div id="div-to-show">
  <p>I am visible</p>
</div>
```

For the general case of checking what CSS rules are being applied to a particular element, you can use `getComputedStyle`:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('div-to-show');
const styleProp = div.style;
const styleDec = window.getComputedStyle(div);
function openDiv() {
  styleProp.display = styleDec.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
#div-to-show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="openDiv()">Clique</p>
<div id="div-to-show">
  <p>I am visible</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) is the better way here

Comment: Also, it works for inline styles. `<div id="div-to-show" style="display: none">`

Comment: If you're going to use `getComputedStyle`, you should cache the result, since it's a live `CSSStyleDeclaration` object, so you shouldn't have to run the function on every click. There are also [a number of caveats to be aware of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Notes)...

Answer (score 0):

1. You should mention function name correctly on `onclick`. `onclick=openDiv` should be replaced to `onclick=openDiv()`.
2. You should define the `display` css style directly on the tag to get `div.style.display` on javascript. `document.getElementById('...').style` will only contain the style attributes which are defined on html tag `style` attribute only so to compare, it will be needed to set `display` attribute on html file directly.

```js
let div = document.getElementById('div-to-show');

function openDiv() {
  if (div.style.display === 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<p onclick="openDiv()">Clique</p>
<div id="div-to-show" style="display: none;">
  <p>I am visible</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #div-to-show{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p onclick="openDiv()">Clique</p>
        <div id="div-to-show">
            <p>I am visible</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            let div = document.getElementById('div-to-show');
          
            function openDiv(){
                if(window.getComputedStyle(div).display === 'none'){
                    div.style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code is wrong the way you write onclick in this tag `<p>`, you need to write onclick in this way:

```
<p onclick="openDiv()">Clique</p>
```

and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Hi as some other examples here explains, you should use the addEvenlListener. If you only what to show the div on the click event you do not need a if statement. You can add a class to the div that sets the display:none. Then in the code you only need to call the remove on the classList on the div. This will not throw an error or do anything if the class is not in the classList. So no need to implement any check logic.

Using the hidden class makes so you do not need to know what the display value was on the div element initially. Less to worry about.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove

```js
let div = document.getElementById('div-to-show')
document.getElementById('p-button').addEventListener("click", openDiv);

function openDiv() {
  div.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
#div-to-show.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="p-button">Clique</p>
<div id="div-to-show" class="hidden">
  <p>I am visible</p>
</div>
```